# Update policy for table in supabase

Tags: supabase

I have created my policies for one table in `supabase` for insert and select but the policy for update was missing so i cannot execute `.update()` method to update one column of the table. So, i created the policy for update but is not working at all, maybe i'm missing something but if i disable the RLS for that table (not recommended) works. The policy created is the following.

```
alter table public.stage_attachment_documents
  enable row level security;

create POLICY "Updates can be performed by users authenticated." on public.stage_attachment_documents
for update to authenticated
with check (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed, the update policy requires a `using` clause to evaluate instead of `with check`

```
create POLICY "Updates can be performed by users authenticated." on public.stage_attachment_documents
for update to authenticated
using (true);
```